# How come these two groups are isomorphic to each other

Tags: group-theory

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$$ and $$\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$$

Where $\mathbb{Z}$ denotes integers and $\times$ the direct product.

Now the book says that yes they are since both are isomorphic to

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 $$

How did we conclude this? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$

Indeed, an isomorphism from the LHS to RHS is given by $1 \mapsto (1, 1)$. (You can check that this is indeed an isomorphism.)

Also $$\mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$$
by the isomorphism $1 \mapsto (1,1)$.

These are instances of the more general [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings).

Finally, note that $A \times B \times C$ is isomorphic to any of its rearrangements, like $A \times C \times B$. In that particular example, it's by the isomorphism $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a,c,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what written in your book, your book is incorrect, because 2 groups can only be isomorph if there exists a bijection between them as sets, which is impossible because $|\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2| = 4$ and $|\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6| = 24$.